# Form Pricing by options

Tags: php, forms

So in a form I have that works great but I am stuck trying to adding pricing to it. Basically the html looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="rightDriver">
                    <!-- Start Form -->

                    <!-- This is the club photos -->
                    <div class="clubPhotos">
                        <div class="club">
                            <img src="clubs/img/praxispi.png" class="clubPhoto" />
                            <span class="clubTitle">Praxis PI</span>
                            <span class="clubSub">Low Launch 9.5</span>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="clubCheckbox4" class="clubCheckbox" name="DriverType" value="Praxis PI Low Launch 9.5" />

                        </div>

                        <div class="club">
                            <img src="clubs/img/praxispi.png" class="clubPhoto" />
                            <span class="clubTitle">Praxis PI</span>
                            <span class="clubSub">Mid-Low Launch 12.5</span>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="clubCheckbox1" class="clubCheckbox" name="DriverType" value="Praxis PI Mid-Low Launch 12.5" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="club">
                            <img src="clubs/img/praxispi.png" class="clubPhoto" />
                            <span class="clubTitle">Praxis PI</span>
                            <span class="clubSub">Mid-High Launch 15.5</span>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="clubCheckbox2" class="clubCheckbox" name="DriverType" value="Praxis PI Mid-High Launch 15.5" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="club last">
                            <img src="clubs/img/praxispi.png" class="clubPhoto" />
                            <span class="clubTitle">Praxis PI</span>
                            <span class="clubSub">High Launch 18.5</span>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="clubSelect" class="clubCheckbox" name="DriverType" value="Praxis PI High Launch 18.5" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- This is the driver order info -->
                    <div class="clubForm">
                        <span class="heading">Club Specs</span>
                        <select name="DriverLength" class="select">
                          <option value="" selected="selected">Driver Length</option>
                          <option value="47.5">47.5</option>
                          <option value="47">47</option>
                          <option value="46.5">46.5</option>
                          <option value="46">46</option>
                          <option value="45.5">45.5</option>
                          <option value="45">45</option>
                          <option value="44.5">44.5</option>
                          <option value="44">44</option>
                          <option value="43.5">43.5</option>
                          <option value="43">43</option>
                          <option value="42.5">42.5</option>
                          <option value="42">42</option>
                        </select>

                        <select name="DriverShaft" class="select">
                          <option value="" selected="selected">Select Shaft</option>
                           <option value="LE- light weight graphite weakest flex">LE- light weight graphite weakest flex</option>
                          <option value="LW- Light weight graphite weak flex">LW- Light weight graphite weak flex</option>
                          <option value="LM- Light weight graphite medium flex">LM- Light weight graphite medium flex</option>
                          <option value="LR- Light weight graphite regular flex">LR- Light weight graphite regular flex</option>
                          <option value="GR- Medium weight graphite regular flex">GR- Medium weight graphite regular flex</option>
                          <option value="SS- Light weight graphite stiff flex">SS- Light weight graphite stiff flex (low torque)</option>
                          <option value="TS- Medium weight graphite stiff flex">TS- Medium weight graphite stiff flex</option>
                          <option value="SX- Light weight graphite X-stiff">SX- Light weight graphite X-stiff</option>
                          <option value="KS- Light weight steel stiff flex">KS- Light weight steel stiff flex</option>
                          <option value="KR- Light weight steel regular flex">KR- Light weight steel regular flex</option>
                          <option value="DX- Heavy weight steel extra stiff">DX- Heavy weight steel extra stiff</option>
                          <option value="DS- Heavy weight steel stiff flex">DS- Heavy weight steel stiff flex</option>
                        </select>

                        <select name="DriverPured" class="select">
                          <option value="" selected="selected">PURE'd</option>
                          <option value="high">High</option>
                          <option value="low">Low</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

And the review looks like this:

```
echo "<h3> Driver</h3>";
                echo "<hr>";
                    echo (!empty($_REQUEST['DriverType'])) ? "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Driver:</span>{$_REQUEST['DriverType']}</div>" : "";
                    echo (!empty($_REQUEST['DriverShaft'])) ? "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Shaft:</span>{$_REQUEST['DriverShaft']}</div>" : "";
                    echo (!empty($_REQUEST['DriverLength'])) ? "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Length:</span>{$_REQUEST['DriverLength']}</div>" : "";
                    echo (!empty($_REQUEST['DriverPured'])) ? "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Pured:</span>{$_REQUEST['DriverPured']}</div>" : "";
```

What I want to happen is add prices to the "shafts" and multiple that to the number of check boxs marked. I am not sure where to even start. I know I can add price to the shaft "value" but then how would I process the name of the shaft if I replace it with a number for "value" I imagine creating an array in PHP but any help would be great. Thanks ahead.

Comment: where is the `<form>`?

Comment: @itachi the actual form is rather long so I just took out a section. I  have it wrapped in a form tag though. The form itself works great. Sends to the review so someone can see the order and then can submit when it then shoots an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite tell if you want to do this in the *form* or on the *server*. If on the *server*, see @Orangepill's answer. Of course, you can also do *both*.

To do this on the client, I'd start considering that your shafts come probably from a database and that you have an ID for each of them.

So you don't need a whole value, you can do with an ID:

```
<option value="17">LE- light weight graphite weakest flex</option>
```

Here, that particular shaft is supposed to have value 17.

Then, if you don't use libraries such as Backbone or jQuery, you can add the value in the options and retrieve it in pure Javascript. Not really very clean (it's actually an instance of the Jaywalking antipattern), but it works:

```
<option value="17:45.99">LE- light weight graphite weakest flex (US$ 45,99)</option>
```

Now in Javascript you can enumerate the various checkboxes and count them, and you can also retrieve the current shaft:

```
<select name="DriverShaft" class="select" id="DriverShaftId">

...

combo = document.getElementById('DriverShaftId');

value = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;

// "value" is now "17:45.99"

vars  = value.split(':');

// vars[0] is "17", vars[1] is "45.99"

cost = numOfCheckedBoxes * vars[1];
```

Now you can put the value into a new field:

```
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = cost;
```

The 'total' element might be

```
Your club will cost US$ <span id="total">...</span>
```

A very simple fiddle (notice that the checkboxes aren't bound; you would probably want them to be, so that the price is updated when the checkboxes are toggled) is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UhdbP/).

However, I'd advise you to check out the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) Javascript library.

To sum it up: when the user submits the form, you receive (on the PHP side) an index into Orangepill's array, or an ID into a database table. From that, you can retrieve again all the shaft information (including price), validate the data and calculate the total(s).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to create a lookup table for your shaft prices.

```
<?php
$shaftPrices = array(
    "LE- light weight graphite weakest flex"=>10,
    "LW- Light weight graphite weak flex"=>10,
    "LM- Light weight graphite medium flex"=>10,
    "LR- Light weight graphite regular flex"=>10,
    "GR- Medium weight graphite regular flex"=>10,
    "SS- Light weight graphite stiff flex"=>10,
    "TS- Medium weight graphite stiff flex"=>10,
    "SX- Light weight graphite X-stiff"=>10,
    "KS- Light weight steel stiff flex"=>10,
    "KR- Light weight steel regular flex"=>10,
    "DX- Heavy weight steel extra stiff"=>10,
    "DS- Heavy weight steel stiff flex"=>10);
```

Then to get the price of the selected shaft you can

```
$shaftPrice = $shaftPrices[$_POST["DriverShaft"]];
```

Comment: That makes sense. Then would I create another array to get the number of "checkboxes" check from the driver section and multiply the two